# Tons of errors due to set arm64 in Excluded Architectures in iOS 14.2 simulators

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios14, xcode12

first of all *disclaimer*: I'm using Mac Mini with Apple Silicon M1.

I have set arm64 in Excluded Architectures due to the known error in Xcode 12:

> The linked framework 'XXXXXX' is missing one or more architectures
> required by this target: arm64.

Since I changed that the simulator's console (only in iOS 14) prints tons of errors when started, regarding wrong hash simulator:

> [db] LSSchemaConfigureForStore failed with error Error
> Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10817 "(null)"
> UserInfo={_LSFunction=_LSSchemaConfigureForStore,
> ExpectedSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0xc853fe2e 5309ad0b
> 8579253e 7b507c34 ... edcdfbe3 457f74e4 }, LSLine=405,
> WrongSimulatorHash={length = 32, bytes = 0x762c6c62 f729dcd9 f2ce6d7b
> bb9aec8d ... d11ece5a 5fc731a0 }}

Anyone else having this problem? Regards.

Comment: I am having this issue on a Mac Mini With Apple Silicon too. Works on my intel...

Comment: Yes, exactly the same error... I read that we shall add the missing architectures in the build settings. But no result.

Comment: Getting the same here.

Comment: Exact same error with Apple Silicon M1 :(

Comment: @Artium I think you can just ping everyone in one comment. But thanks for the info!

Comment: @aheze Sorry, did not know that :)

Answer (score 16):

I had a somewhat different but similar issue when building on M1 MBP with Xcode running with Rosetta. Some of Apple's APIs fail and together with failing there is this error printed to the console.

In my opinion this is some kind of a simulator bug and it is present as of Xcode 12.3. Maybe 12.4 solves it, but I did not try.

Anyway, what solved it for me was to download iOS 13.7 simulator runtime.

[image]

[image]

And then create a new simulator using this iOS version:

[image]

If this solution worked for you but you must have iOS 14, you can try other 14.x version. Maybe it's an issue only with the latest.

Comment: For others viewing this, I've tried every iOS 14 simulator and they all have the same issue. On 14.0 my apps won't even install/run, it seems broken under Rosetta. On 13.7 some apps work but I get random EXC_BAD_ACCESS crashes in 3rd party SDK's (like Facebook) that don't occur on Intel or in the real world.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I saw these errors using React Native after ejecting from expo. Specifically, running `expo run:ios` ([more info](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/customizing/)). I see no such errors after stopping that initial session and running another again, right after, using `npm run ios`.

Seems like the normal npm-run command starts a simulator with the correct architecture. However, the final step in the `expo run:ios` process does not.

Comment: I had the same issue with ionic, running from Xcode doesn't work but `ionic capacitor run ios -l --external` works fine

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of these loggings by adding `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable` to the Environment Variables's Arguments.

[image: Product -> Edit Schema -> Run -> Arguments]

Comment: Not helpful to suppress the warnings, they're shown with a reason. As @Artium mentioned API fail when running Xcode and Simulators under x86_64 Rosetta. In my case `url.resourceValues` always return `nii`. But might be useful in other cases where it's just about the warnings though.